# how can i add a mouse click to this program that will increment a score by one each time the ball is clicked in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

How can i add a mouse click to this program that will increment a score by one each time the ball is clicked in C#?

```
 namespace Ball_timer_2005
 {
  public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
  {

    const int radius = 20;
    const int velocity = 5;

    int xC, yC, xDelta=10, yDelta=10, xSize, ySize;  // class level variables

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;      // Tell form to redraw itself when         resized
        timer1.Start();
        Form1_Resize(this, EventArgs.Empty);  // Force a Resize Event as pgm     starts
        //
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        this.timer1.Interval = 25;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Bouncing Ball";
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);

    }
    #endregion


    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }



    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        xSize = this.ClientSize.Width;   // Set current window size
        ySize = this.ClientSize.Height;
        xC = xSize/2;                    // Place ball in center of window 
        yC = ySize/2;
        DrawBall();                       // Draw the ball in the window        
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawBall();                       // Draw ball in next frame of animation       
    }

    private void DrawBall()
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
        g.FillEllipse(b, xC-radius, yC-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius); //erase old ball
        xC += xDelta;                                                   //move ball
        yC += yDelta;
        if ((xC+radius >= ClientSize.Width) || (xC - radius <= 0)) //check for wall hits
            xDelta = -xDelta;
        if ((yC+radius >= ClientSize.Height) || (yC - radius <= 0))
            yDelta = -yDelta;
        b = new SolidBrush(Color.GreenYellow);                                   // draw new ball
        g.FillEllipse(b, xC-radius, yC-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
        b.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }




}
}
```

1.this is the code i have so far can some one help ???
1.this is the code i have so far can some one help ???
1.this is the code i have so far can some one help ???

Comment: Please clean up your code first. What's the exact issue?

Comment: i need to be able to click on the moving ball and keep score on how many times you clicked on the ball

Comment: Yes, we got that from the title. Where in your code is this reflected? What is the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: this is the code for the moving ball i need help adding the score and the mouse click. its not in the code yet i need help adding those two things in it.

Comment: Sadly, that is not what StackOverflow is for. Show us what you have tried for this specific issue (remove irrelevant code as well) and tell us what the problems where that you faced. We don't write code when no effort is shown.

Comment: i understand but how can i show what ive tried when i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Handling `MouseClick` event of the Form.

**Step1:** Store the `Ellipse` Co-ordinates into the `Region`  to identify the position of the `Mouse Click` later.

```
        //Declare it as class members
        List<Region> regionList = new List<Region>();
        int EclipseX = 10;
        int EclipseY = 50;
        int BallWidth = 100;
        int BallHeight = 100;

//inside paint function
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);           
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, EclipseX,EclipseY, BallWidth, BallHeight);
regionList.Add(new Region(new Rectangle(EclipseX,EclipseY, BallWidth, BallHeight)));
```

**Step2:** now declare the `MouseClick` event of the `Form`

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
```

**Step3:** now handle the `MouseClick` event of the `Form`.

1. the `MouseClick` event provides `MouseEventArgs` parameter here `e`.
2. this `MouseEventArgs` has two properties.
3. first `property` is `X` gives you the `X-axis` Location of the
   `Mouse Click`.
4. second `property` is `Y` gives you the `Y-axis` location of the `Mouse Click`.
5. you need to compare these `X` and `Y` values with existing `Region` values using `IsVisible` Property.
6. you need to get the each `Region` from the `List` (which was added while drawing
   `Ellipse`) and use `IsVisible` Property of the `Region` class to
   detect whether  mouse clicked on the `Ellipse` or not.

   ```
           //declare it as class member
           int MouseClicksCount = 0;
           bool isfound=false;
           //event handler
           private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
           {       
               isfound=false;
               foreach(Region r in regionList)
               {
               if (r.IsVisible(e.X, e.Y))
               {
                   isfound=true;
                   break;
               }
               }
               if (isfound)
                   MouseClicksCount++;
           }
   ```

**Complete Solution(Sample code):**

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int MouseClicksCount = 0;
        List<Region> regionList = new List<Region>();

        int EclipseX = 10;
        int EclipseY = 50;
        int BallWidth = 100;
        int BallHeight = 100;
        bool isfound=false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
            this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
        }



        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {       
            isfound=false;
            foreach(Region r in regionList)
            {
            if (r.IsVisible(e.X, e.Y))
            {
                isfound=true;
                break;
            }
            }
            if (isfound)
                MouseClicksCount++;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);           
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, EclipseX,EclipseY, BallWidth, BallHeight);
            regionList.Add(new Region(new Rectangle(EclipseX,EclipseY, BallWidth, BallHeight)));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much would this cod work if i just added it to the end of my existing code ?

Comment: @user3023866: you are welcome :) , this code is sample code it works if you copy entire code but in yours you need to change according to this.please let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/317766/mouse-coordinates-within-a-form

You may be able to us this to detect an overlap of mouse position/ ball width radius